# How to write JSON serialization in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, serialization, swift4

i have this body to send for backend `{

```
    "cart": 
        {
            "products": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "quantity": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ],
            "card": 
                    {
                        "id": "card_21378921w"
                    }

        }

}`
```

I try create with codable object:

```
    struct Cart: Codable  {

        var id: Int!
        var quantity: Int!

 private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "id"
        case quantity = "quantity"

    }

   }

    var cart: [Cart]!
```

Then try to create a Dictionary as String,Any but when I try use

**try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)**
 i can't create a correct json file to send for my backend and server returns status code 422

How can I fix that ? I'm new using swift 4 and codables

Function

```
 static func createCheckout(accessToken: String, buildingId: Int,products:[Cart], card_id: String,completion: @escaping (CommonResponse?, _ error: Int?) -> ()) {
    let url = Url.createCheckout(buildingId: buildingId)
    let parameters = Params.createCheckout(products: products, card_id: card_id)



    if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(parameters)) {

        print(parameters)
        print("is not a valid json object")
        return
    }

    let encodedParameters = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpBody = encodedParameters

    Alamofire.request(request).responseDecodableObject(decoder: JSONDecoder()) { (response: DataResponse<CommonResponse>) in
        let repo = response.result.value
        let error = response.response?.statusCode

        completion(repo, error)
    }
```

Params

```
static func createCheckout(products:[Cart], card_id: String) -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    let products: [String: Any] = ["products": products]
    let card_number: [String: Any] = ["id": card_id]

    return ["cart" : products, "card": card_number]
}
```

Comment: how did you call the JSONSerialization in your code? Can you add it to your post?

Comment: @ChristianAbella I updated answer with more details, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

Create correct struct that match with my JSON

```
   struct Checkout: Codable {
    var cart: Cart
}

struct Cart: Codable {
    var products: [Product]
    var card: Card
}

struct Card: Codable {
    var id: String
}

struct Product: Codable {
    var id, quantity: Int
}
```

Then call properly using Alamofire and JSONEncoder

```
 static func createCheckout(accessToken: String, buildingId: Int,checkout: Checkout,completion: @escaping (_ error: Int?) -> ()) {
        let url = Url.createCheckout(buildingId: buildingId)

        let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(checkout)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = encodedData

         Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            let error = response.response?.statusCode
            completion(error)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your `Cart` struct doesn't match the structure of your json. Try something like this:

```
struct Product: Codable {
   let id: Int
   let quantity: Int
}

struct Card: Codable {
   let id: String
}

struct Cart: Codable {
   let products: [Product]
   let card: Card
}
```

Create your `Cart` value and then convert it to json using a `JSONEncoder`.

---

Some other suggestions:

- Try to avoid implicit unwrapped values like `Int!`. You'll encounter a lot of fatal errors if you use this code in production.
- You don't need to redefine your coding keys if the names of your fields already matches them.